# keyup Event listener doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, keyup

Soo basically I have a button assigned to variable (changeColor). I want to trigger this button whenever I press the space key.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if (event == 32) {
        changeColor.click()
    }
})
```

However, this doesn't work unless I'm focused on the button - clicking it before pressing the space bar, clicking anywhere out of it will disable the key trigger.

I tried deleting the if condition so that any key would trigger the button and worked perfectly.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
        changeColor.click()
})
```

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: This sounds about right for the 'keyup' event, maybe you should rather try keydown event instead? Keyup literally waits for you to release your space bar before it fires. Keydown fires when it is pushed down.

Comment: I think you mean `event.keyCode`

Comment: People used to use `event.keyCode || event.which` but now it's deceprated. Use `event.key`.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to change `if (event == 32)` to `if (event.keyCode == 32)`

Note: It would be good practice if you could use strict equality `===` instead of abstract equality `==`

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH I ALMOST GAVE UP

Comment: @Amer Al-Gendi I think `keyCode` is deprecated now use `event.key === " "` or `event.code === "Space"` instead

Comment: `event.keyCode` uses numbers and `event.key` uses strings. So if you want to use `event.key` if should be `event.key === "space"` . If you want something fancier, you can also try `event.code` :)

Comment: @StarPass No. It won't work. You should use  `event.key === " "`. It doesn't return "space".
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values

Comment: @StartPass For more details about `keyCode` read also this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode `it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards`

Answer (score 1):

`event.keyCode` and `event.which` are both deceprated.

Use `event.key` instead.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if (event.key === " ") {
        changeColor.click();
    }
});
```

**NOTE:**
`event.key` returns a string, which values are different from `event.keyCode`. You can see a list of values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values).

Also, you might have a look at this:

> Older browsers may return "Spacebar" instead of " " for the Space Bar key. Firefox did so until version 37, as did Internet Explorer 9, 10, and 11.

Answer (score 0):

Use **event.key** instead of event.

```
    if (event.key === " ") {
       //some logic
    }
```